# Is console.log() a javascript built-in method?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with angular js. My project includes only the angular.min.js file, with no other references of js files like javascript etc.
The code which makes request to the server is as follows:

```js
var app = angular
  .module("myModule", [])
  .controller("myController", function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("WebService.asmx/GetAllEmployees")
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.employees = response.data;
        console.log(response.data)
      }, function(reason) {
        $scope.error = reason.data;
      });
  });
```

I'm wondering about the following line:

```
console.log(response.data)
```

I could not figure out who's property this function is?

Is this browser builtin function?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console

Comment: Why downward on this ask?

Comment: Likely because you did not even try reading the documentation

Comment: I tried and found some differences and was not quite assure. that's why i decided to put it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log()` is a feature for debugging purposes. It allows a script to log data to the JavaScript console.

If you want to display the message from `console.log()` in your browser, you need to access the browser's console.

Comment: Or stdout in node - a browser is not always needed

Comment: @mplungjan I just answered based on his scenario. The 'You' was for Radhe

Comment: I know - just wanted to give you an idea why someone might have voted you down

Comment: @mplungjan ah yes, thanks :) I should have written it as a comment. I edited the answer

Comment: I don't know why someone down voted me?

Comment: @JohnSmith thanks for your answer. i got the difference.

Comment: It was already answered 3 minutes before. Perhaps that is why - also some people vote answers down on poor questions

Comment: It might be poor but I wanted to know the differences. people do judge by appearance?

Comment: @RadheSham you could have found the answer without having to ask here, pretty fast. A bit of research before asking questions won't usually get you a downvote

Comment: okay @JohnSmith will care next time.
any way thanks for your suggetions

Comment: @RadheSham happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's built in function.

**console** is an object which resides in any global (for example **window**) object of JavaScript. This object contains various methods, out of which **log** is the one. This displays anything you put on browser console.